# Implementing Search Function to search in ListView by specific TextView

Tags: android, listview, searchview

[Auction List Image][1] I am trying to implement a search function to search through the ListView by a specific TextView which is the ItemName TextView as shown in the image such as "Adidas Shoes" & "Nike Shoes" .That TextView is id as txtName. Currently, with these codes, there is no error, but the search function is not doing anything. How do I implement the search to actually search by looking through the txtName TextView?

Adapter:

```
public class AuctionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

ValueFilter valueFilter;


private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Model> auctionList;




public AuctionListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Model> auctionList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.auctionList = auctionList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return auctionList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return auctionList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Model> filterList = new ArrayList<Model>();
            for (int i = 0; i < auctionList.size(); i++) {
                if ((auctionList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    Model model = new Model(auctionList.get(i).getId(),auctionList.get(i).getName(),
                            auctionList.get(i).getDescription(),auctionList.get(i).getPrice(),auctionList.get(i).getDuration()
                    ,auctionList.get(i).getImage());
                        filterList.add(model);


                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = auctionList.size();
            results.values = auctionList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                  FilterResults results) {
        auctionList = (ArrayList<Model>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}



private class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName,txtDescription,txtPrice,txtDuration;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout,null);
        holder.txtName=row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtDescription=row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        holder.txtPrice=row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.txtDuration=row.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
        holder.imageView=row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Model model = auctionList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(model.getPrice());
    holder.txtDuration.setText(model.getDuration());


    byte[] auctionImage = model.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(auctionImage,0,auctionImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return row;
}


}
```

AuctionList.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu,menu);

    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Its not doing anything because you haven't write any code to make it work .`SearchView ` does not filter data itself .

Comment: Can you tell me how do I search by the TextView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827646/how-to-implement-search-in-custom-listview-in-android

Comment: Is there any ways that I can make minimal changes to my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Create a private class inside your adapter

```
  /**
 * Custom filter for Brand list
 * Filter content in brand list according to the search text
 */
private class BrandFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint!=null && constraint.length()>0) {
            ArrayList<User> tempList = new ArrayList<User>();

            // search content in Brand list
            for (User user : brandList) {
                if (mList.getBrandName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempList.add(user);
                }
            }

            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = friendList.size();
            filterResults.values = friendList;
        }

        return filterResults;
    }

    /**
     * Notify about filtered list to ui
     * @param constraint text
     * @param results filtered result
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredList = (ArrayList<User>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Implement Filterable to your adapter , and write the following code to your Override function getfilter.

```
 if (brandFilter == null) {
        Filter = new BrandFilter();
    }

    return friendFilter;
```

Just call this method inside your activity , on onQueryTextChange

```
        mAdapetr.getFilter().filter(newText);
```

Comment: What's the brandFilter may I ask?

Comment: @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (brandFilter == null) {
            Filter = new BrandFilter();
        }

        return friendFilter;
    }

Comment: Hi I managed to make it work already. However, whenever i search,and then backspace the words, the listview doesnt refresh back to its original. How do I solve this?

Comment: you need to clear the list , and notify your adapter .

Comment: I have given the example form my code base . you can make the changes accordingly to your adapter . every time you write a query of anything , jus notify your adapter .

Comment: I have edited my post with my new codes, may you take a look and see whats the problem?

Comment: You are  making changes to your original list, instead create a temp list for  filter data .

Comment: have you debug your original array list size ?

Answer (score 0):

For temp list :

```
    private ArrayList<Model> filteredList;
```

and in your constructor

```
this.filteredList = auctionList
```

while publishing result ,  `/**
     * Notify about filtered list to ui
     * @param constraint text
     * @param results filtered result
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredList = (ArrayList<Model>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`